# Gridsome Graphql filter variable

Tags: vue.js, graphql, server-side-rendering, gridsome

Im trying to query a collection and filter it depends on the $path var
but it either returns empty or throwing an error

```
<page-query>
query Gallery($path: String!){
  photos : allPhotos(filter: { nameFromGalleries: { contains: [$path]}}){
    edges{
      node{
        nameFromGalleries
        galleries
        attachments{
          thumbnails{
            full{
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</page-query>
```

for another query on the same page it works just fine

```
  gallery : gallery(path: $path){
    title
    children{
      name
      path
    }
  }
```

Comment: In the first query you're passing in the variables/parameters wrong. The variables should be in form of an object if they're nested. Something like `allPhotos(filter : { nameFromGalleries : $path })...` then you'll access `filter.nameFromGalleries` in the backend to get the value of $path

Comment: Thanks @kimobrian254, I edited question, still filter doesnt work :(

how does the variables work here?

Comment: what's the exact error? I might be able to help with some context.

Comment: Variables are just like named function parameters like `queryName(var1: value, var2: value, var3: { varA: value, varB: value}, var4: [values])`. This demos either single variables, objects as variables or array as variables.